# UI Button Connection

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uikit, iboutlet

I am unable to press the stop recording button, I feel it may have happened after I changed its size because before it was working. I checked my code and the `UIbutton` is still connected. I am wondering if resizing something can change the configuration for that button.

[image]

Comment: Please paste your code as text...

Answer (score 1):

Well, the button is not supposed to be 'clickable' after the `isEnabled` is set to false in your `viewDidLoad()`.

You can read more here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/1618217-isenabled

Comment: Thank You! that was exactly the issue

Answer (score 0):

You should set isEnabled to true in your viewDidLoad().